# Codeigniter: Group by and get the latest record from the joined table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
$this -> db -> select('users.*');
$this -> db -> select('timerecord.*');
$this -> db -> from('users');
$this -> db -> join('timerecord', 'users.id = timerecord.id');
//$this -> db -> where(array('users.id'=>$user_id), NULL, FALSE);
$this -> db -> where('users.status', 'Verified');
//$this -> db -> where('users.id', 'timerecord.id');
$this -> db -> order_by('timerecord.timeId', 'DESC');
$this -> db -> group_by('timerecord.id, users.id');
```

i want to get records from both users and timerecord table but timerecord shows multiple rows because of duplicated id, and now i used group_by to limit the row in timerecord however the record is not showing the latest record i also used orderby but no luck, please someone help me, thanks!

Comment: Try to print `$this->last_query()`. and see if that's what you wanted

Comment: unfortunately, Mr. ss56, that's not the output i wanted, what i want is a single row result per timerecord.id, but it shows multiple rows because of multiple ids inserted on it, what i want is to show only a single row and it will be the latest record in timerecord table. thanks!

Comment: you can try limit in that case `$this->db->limit(1);` at the end of your query. have you tried it?

Comment: it can't be mr. ss56, because it will limit into 1 row only, i'm so sorry.. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.approve').click(function(){
                return confirm("Verify this user?");
            });
            $('.delete').click(function(){
                return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this account, everything will be deleted including its time record?");
            });
        }); 
    </script>
    <div class="empRec">
        <div class="empRec-content">
            <table class="tn">
              <tr>
                <th class="tn-4apw">Employee Name</th>
                <th class="tn-4apw">Date</th>
                <th class="tn-4apw">Day</th>
                <th class="tn-4apw">Time In/Out</th>
                <th class="tn-4apw"></th>
              </tr>
              <?php 
                foreach($getUsers as $row): 
                $timeStat = $row->status;
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td class="tn-ixdt"><?php if($timeStat == 'IN') { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/ico-online.png'); ?>" style="width:10px;">
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/ico-offline.png'); ?>" style="width:10px;">           
                <?php } echo $row->name ?></td>
                <td class="tn-ixdt"><?php echo $row->dateToday ?></td>
                <td class="tn-ixdt"><?php echo $row->day ?></td>
                <td class="tn-ixdt"><?php echo $row->timeIn ?> - <?php echo $row->timeOut ?></td>
                <td class="tn-ixdt" style="text-align:right;"><button class="view" name="view"><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/ico-view.png'); ?>"></img></button><button class="delete" name="delete"><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/ico-delete.png'); ?>"></img></button></td>
              </tr>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- Employee Record Content  -->
        <div class="empRec-bg"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- EMPLOYEE RECORD CONTAINER -->
</div>
<!-- CONTAINER -->
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->query("SELECT users.*, timerecord.* FROM (users) 
JOIN timerecord ON users.id = timerecord.id WHERE users.status = 'Verified'
group by users.id, timerecord.dateToday order by dateToday")->get()->result();
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' timerecord. FROM (users) JOIN timerecord ON users.id = timerecord.id WHERE user' at line 1

Comment: aww, the code turned into txtformatting. i'll paste it here.

PS: I'm not MR.

$this->db->query("SELECT users.*, timerecord.* FROM (users) JOIN timerecord ON users.id = timerecord.id WHERE users.status = 'Verified' group by users.id, timerecord.dateToday order by dateToday")->get()->result();

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_result::get() in C:\wamp\www\cvo-attendance\application\models\admin.php on line 54

:( that's the error. :(

Comment: try removing the ->get()

just ->result();

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select('MAX(a.login_time) as login_time')

->from('bs_login_report a')

->group_by('a.user_id')

->get();
```

using this '**MAX(a.login_time) as login_time**' you can achieve last row using

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

```
$this -> db -> select('users.*');
$this -> db -> select('timerecord.*');
$this -> db -> from('users');
$this -> db -> join('timerecord', 'users.id = timerecord.timerecord.user_id');
//USE THE NAME OF THE ROW WHERE USER'S IDs ARE INSERTED ON YOUR TIMERECORD TABLE,
// THAT'S HOW YOU JOIN TABLE, RIGHT? 
// I ASSUME THAT YOU ARE JOINING USER'S ID AND TIMERECORD'S ID ON YOUR PREVIOUS POST //
//$this -> db -> where(array('users.id'=>$user_id), NULL, FALSE);
$this -> db -> where('users.status', 'Verified');
//$this -> db -> where('users.id', 'timerecord.id');
$this -> db -> order_by('timerecord.timeId', 'DESC');
$this -> db -> group_by('timerecord.id, users.id');
```

Comment: Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'timerecord.timerecord.user_id' in 'on clause'

SELECT `users`.*, `timerecord`.* FROM (`users`) JOIN `timerecord` ON `users`.`id` = `timerecord`.`timerecord`.`user_id` WHERE `users`.`status` = 'Verified' GROUP BY `timerecord`.`id`, `users`.`id` ORDER BY `timerecord`.`timeId` DESC

Filename: C:\wamp\www\cvo-attendance\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

this is what the error says mr. user07192010, thanks!

Comment: what is the column name for the user's id on your timerecord table?

Comment: I told you to use the column's name for user's id on your timerecord table for this part:

$this -> db -> join('timerecord', 'users.id = timerecord.timerecord.user_id');


timerecord.timerecord.user_id
---> replace 'timerecord.user_id' with the column name for user's id 
in your timerecord table.

Do you get what I mean?

Comment: yes, but here is the new error, do you think mr. user07192010 its on the duplicated timerecord.timerecord?

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'timerecord.timerecord.id' in 'on clause'

SELECT `users`.*, `timerecord`.* FROM (`users`) JOIN `timerecord` ON `users`.`id` = `timerecord`.`timerecord`.`id` WHERE `users`.`status` = 'Verified' GROUP BY `timerecord`.`id`, `users`.`id` ORDER BY `timerecord`.`timeId` DESC

Filename: C:\wamp\www\cvo-attendance\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: can you please give me a manual query mr. user07192010 like $this -> db -> query("SELECT t.uuid, t.version, t.datetime 
    FROM table t JOIN (
        SELECT version, MAX(datetime) Maxdatetime
        FROM table
        WHERE uuid='bla'
        GROUP BY version
    ) r ON t.version = r.version AND t.datetime = r.Maxdatetime
    WHERE t.uuid='bla'
    ORDER BY t.datetime des"); like that one?

Comment: or can i just use two foreach in views? how can i do that? please help me, i will make you my hero if you can help me from this misery, thanks!

Comment: repeating the 'timerecord' isn't what I'm telling you to do so. THat just means, after the timerecord.[insert the column's name for the user's id here on your timerecord table] what is the column name of your timrecord unique id? is it 'id'? then, it shouldn't be timerecord.id

cause you are joining users.id to timerecord.[USER'S ID COLUMN NAME FOR YOUR timerecord table] .. you are joining the relationship between the two tables.

Comment: is there a chance that they will in at the same day?

Comment: yes they can in at the same day, let say 3 employees using the system they are going to in and out everyday on the system i made.

Comment: I mean, user 1 will timeIn twice at the same day? Or user 1 will just use the system twice, when he will time in and time out?

Comment: no, they can only time in and out once a day, i used validation for that mr.user07192010, thanks!

Comment: are your data inserted came from just a test? try removing first the repeated data and just leave those correct time in and time out from your database. maybe the code is correct but you've inserted dummy data from the database repeatedly

Comment: yup i deleted it already, but still, it doesn't show the recent record inserted in timerecord, it shows the first record, do you think because of group_by?

Comment: What are you trying to get? Just a row?  Just the last inserted item? 
If yes,

SELECT users.*,timerecord.* FROM (users) JOIN timerecord ON users.id = timerecord.id WHERE users.status = 'Verified' group by users.id, timerecord.dateToday order by dateToday desc limit 1